# Creating a function in react app to make the whole text bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, constants

I m creating a react application a clone of wordcounter.com. I am facing issues in creating a const function that can change the whole text in bold with `onclick` event.

```
const handleBold =(event) =>{
        let newText= text.bold();
        setText(newText)
    }
 <button className="btn btn-primary mx-1" onClick={handleBold}>Bold</button>
```

I created a button added `onclick` event in it and created a const function to call on that `onclick` function but it is not working and the text is not getting bold.

Comment: where does the `text` come from?

Comment: Please, add more code and information about the problem. It's not possible to what's `text` or the function is properly used. Apart from that, If your function `bold` is the native method `bold`, you must know that is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) and is not recommended anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something more along the lines of:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [isBold, setIsBold] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setIsBold(prevIsBold => !prevIsBold);
  }

  return (
    <p onClick={handleClick} style={{ fontWeight: isBold ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}>
      This is a paragraph element that becomes bold when clicked.
    </p>
  );
}
```